# How to pass a string as default argument in C++

Tags: c++, default-parameters

How can I properly pass a const string, for example: "Hello" as a default parameter to a constructor without getting any warnings and errors? In other words how can I preserve memory for them before the function is called?

Comment: What warnings/errors you are talking about?

Comment: @arrowd One major one is:C:...\main.cpp|26|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|

Comment: by the way i need the char* cos it's part of our homework

Comment: Use `const char*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

const char *defString = "Hello";
void foo(const char *str = defString) {
    std::cout << str;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    foo("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way? What if I want to give the str sth made of 50 characters in the function??? (Without using "new" keyword to allocate memory)